# Значение параметра в ответе и в JSON объекте, который спарсил браузер отличается

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

В общем передаю через Ajax некоторые параметры и вижу такую картину:

Это спасрил Google Chrome

[image]

Это исходная строка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть?

Comment: Такой магии не бывает. Значит что-то не так сделали. Без каких либо примеров (что и куда передаёте и как проверить) сказать тут будет абсолютно нечего

Comment: Весь json покажите, а лучше текстом.

Comment: Вы разные поля сверяете, и, вполне возможно, что и у разных пользователей.

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело в том, что число больше, чем [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (`9007199254740991`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых Вы выделили разные ключи `bot_streamid` и `user_streamid`

Но значения все равно отличаются, однако ничего удивительного в этом нет, это число больше чем `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

```js
var json = '[76561198193808842]'
console.log(JSON.parse(json)[0])
```

Используйте строки.

Comment: можно даже проще пример: `console.log(76561198193808842)`

Comment: без сомнения, я просто хотел изобразить то что произошло